# Play! Framework: File not served after upload until play clean

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

If I do a file upload to the file system (to the *public* assets directory) in production mode, the file is not served afterwards. I need to run the *clean* command. I get a file not found error. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a custom Assets controller, now it seems to work properly:

```
package customcontrollers

import controllers.Assets
import play.api.mvc.Action
import play.api.mvc.AnyContent
import play.api.mvc.Results.Ok
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api._

object UploadedImageAssets {
  def at(file: String): Action[AnyContent] = Action {
    Ok.sendFile(Play.getFile("public/uploaded-images/"+file))
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't like this answer, but there is no way to achieve this easily.

Because, "[it's not a very good way to do things, it is unreliable, it doesn't scale, and there are security concerns](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/upload%2420public%7Csort%3adate/play-framework/3_H_YmxzQUo/iHj7U8CHR3sJ)". (I don't agree with this, but it's a fact).

The best solution is to store your file in a database, or to upload it to another service like S3.

Comment: Thanks. The easiest solution would be to disable caching on the Assets object. Now I wrote a custom Assets singleton that replaces the built-in Assets class...

Answer (score 3):

Although sending files as an action's Result is possible (what you proved) I'd suggest to store *public* uploads outside of the application and serving it with common HTTP server.

Reasons are simple:

- if you will need to add/replace files fast, you can do it with common FTP client
- you don't need to redeploy your app if you're adding files with 3rd part client
- HTTP server serves static files just faster, it manages cache headers out of the box (cause it's its job) etc. Server doesn't need to rewrite file to the result.
- using subdomain for this, you can create a'la CDN solution
- app's code is just smaller

Comment: Good points. At least your third point is important to me. I will perhaps make use of Apache2 to serve uploaded files.

Comment: If you don't need to use Apache specific features, probably nginx will be better choice for this task